# Issue with Ajax and JSON Response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm a pretty novice programmer who is making an application where there are multiple divs with a class of **jcontainer**. Each **jcontainer** has an id associated with it, which corresponds with a field called **apptid** in a database. In the Jquery, I send out an AJAX request every five seconds to a php page to retrieve a field called **currentlocation** in the database (that corresponds with the **apptid**), which happens for each **jcontainer**.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class='jcontainer' data-param='jcontainer_IDNUMBER'>

  <button class='checkIn' data-param='button_IDNUMBER'>Check In</button>
  <form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
       <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param='location_IDNUMBER'>
            <option value='1'>Exam Room</option>
            <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
            <option value='3'>X-Ray Room</option>
            <option value='1000'>Check Out</option>
       </select>
  </form>
  <div class='finished' style='color:#ff0000;'>Checked Out</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function(){

    $('.jcontainer').each(function() {
        var $e = $(this);
        var dataid = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'heartbeat.php',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataid,
            success: function(data){
                var msg = $.parseJSON(response);
                alert(msg);
            }
        });

    });
  },5000);

  //other code that I didn't post, because it's not really relevant, but can post if needed be
```

and php page:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';

$username = '******';

$password = '*************';

$apptid = $_POST['dataid'];

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT currentlocation FROM schedule WHERE apptid = :apptid");
$statement->execute(array(':apptid' => $apptid));
$row = $statement->fetch();

$currentlocation = array('CurrentLocation' => $row['currentlocation']);
echo json_encode($currentlocation);

?>
```

The problem is I can't get any response from the alert(msg). Why is this? I checked Chrome Developer and no errors came up.

The end goal is to have the currentlocation number recorded in a jquery variable. ex -> `var currentLocation = Number`

Thanks for any and all help, and if you need more details to clear things up, I can happily post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block of code:

```
success: function(data){
            var msg = $.parseJSON(response);
            alert(msg);
        }
```

should read

```
success: function(data){
            var msg = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(msg);
        }
```

cause the `response` variable is not declared and undefined so you should use the `data` variable in your parseJSON method as that is the actual data received. Hope this solves it for you.

Comment: The alert popped up, but the value was null. Any ideas?

Comment: That means you passed null to the function

Comment: If still no errors yet do not use `$.parseJSON` as the data you are expecting is JSON already specified by the dataType parameter and second of all either use `alert(data)` or as someone below suggested `console.log(data)` and see what you get. Also if you are using Chrome you can see the request headers/responses on the developer interface under the Network tab. To pop this interface out right-click on the page and choose Inspect Element and then you have all the tabs there including the Network tab. Find the request to heartbeat.php and see what's happening there.

Comment: Mind you that you should pop up the interface first and, with it open, initiate the ajax request so if you open it afterwards just refresh your page and initiate the request again and you'll have it in your list on the Network tab.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `$.parseJSON`, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON since you're telling it `dataType: "json"`. Your `alert` should then say `Object`. Use your browser console, and `console.log(data)` to see the object's structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON("heartbeat.php?jsoncallback=?",
    {dataid},
    function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    }
);
```

Then in your PHP, you have to use the jsoncallback like so:

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($currentlocation).')';
```

Two things to notice here.

1, I put the return from the json `data` in the `console`, rather than `alert()`

2, You might need to check you `dataid` variable as it uses traditional array values (`id:3,key:value`) method rather than "`id=3&key=vaule`"

Answer (score 1):

you may use my library that does that for you automatically http://phery-php-ajax.net

```php
function heartbeat($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;

  $hostname = 'localhost';

  $username = '******';

  $password = '*************';

  $apptid = $data['id'];

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);
  $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT currentlocation FROM schedule WHERE apptid = :apptid");
  $statement->execute(array(':apptid' => $apptid));
  $row = $statement->fetch();

  // If you want to manipulate the DOM inside the jcontainer use:
  // $r->this()->find('.locationSelect'); 
  // for examplee
  return $r->set_var('currentLocation', $row['currentlocation']); //set the global var
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'heartbeat' => 'heartbeat'
))->process();
```

And you'd change your HTML to fit the Phery library

```html
<div class='jcontainer' data-remote='heartbeat' data-args="<?php echo Phery::args(array('id' => $number)); /* place your number in here */ ?>" id='jcontainer_IDNUMBER'>
  <button class='checkIn' data-param='button_IDNUMBER'>Check In</button>
  <form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
     <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param='location_IDNUMBER'>
        <option value='1'>Exam Room</option>
        <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
        <option value='3'>X-Ray Room</option>
        <option value='1000'>Check Out</option>
     </select>
  </form>
  <div class='finished' style='color:#ff0000;'>Checked Out</div>
</div>
```

And your new jquery each will be:

```js
$('.jcontainer').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.phery('remote'); // call the remote AJAX with the data
});
```

if you want to check the data in the dev console, you can use, the PHP variable will be dumped in the console

```php
$r->dump_var($row, $apptid);
```